# simplify $4\sqrt{3-2x^2}-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Simplify:
$4\sqrt{3-2x^{2}} - 1$

I get $4\sqrt{3}-9x$. Not sure this is correct, or if it is most simplified in the form above.

There's no explanation of steps in the material I'm reading from.

Comment: Can you include given answer of the above question in material in your post.

Comment: How did you get your answer?  It is certainly incorrect.  (Plug in nearly any value for x.)  I don't think it can be simplified.

Answer (score 2):

This certainly can't be right,
because for $x=0$
the first expression has value
$4\sqrt{3}-1$
and the second is
$4\sqrt{3}$.

Please show what you have done,
and make sure that
you have specified
the right problem.

Comment: Even less accurate for x=1.  The first becomes 3 and second 4rt (3)-9.

Comment: Even less accurate with $x=2$: one is well-defined and one isn't (in reals).